# Depending on Select option change others value on div and input field in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-selectors, laravel-7

I'm in the learning period. I need a solution but I couldn't find it.

I have a dynamic select option. I want that, when the select option is changed it will show all the related columns from the database in another div.

**DB Table Name:** Offers

**Column Name:** id, name, details, recharge

**Controller:**

```
$offers = Offer::all();
return view('sim_sale', compact('offers'));
```

**Blade File:**

```
<select name="offer_id" id="offer" class="form-control">
    <option value=""> Select Offer</option>
    @foreach ( $offers as $row )
    <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
 <div id="offer-details">
     {{$offers->details}
 </div> 
 <input type="text" value="{{$offers->recharge}}" id="offer-recharge" />
```

Here, if the select option changes, it will show the details and recharge, else nothing will show in these fields. Also, Users can put data in the input field.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: THen you are going to meed to research AJAX that is how this is normally done

Comment: Put an id on the options and add a class with display none (d-none for bootstrap) if the event is triggered (tbf no clue but probably something like onclick) u should be able to do a removeclass on the id

Comment: I think, I don't need to add or remove class. Here in ` {{$offers->details}}` and ` {{$offers->recharge}}` value will show depending on the select id. If the select id is 3, then it will show the 3rd id's details, recharge column data from the database. I think ajax suggestion is perfect. But I don't know how to write the ajax code. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a solution for this.
Here is my code:

```
 <select name="offer_id" id="parent_id" class="form-control dynamic" data-dependent="details">
       <option value=""> Select Offer</option>
       @foreach ( $offers as $row )
       <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
       </select>
       @foreach($offers as $row)  
       <div class="some"  id="some_{{ $row->id }}"  style="display:none;">
        {{ $row->details }}
       </div>
       @endforeach

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#parent_id').on('change',function(){
$(".some").hide();
var some = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
$("#some_" + some).show();}); </script>
```